# Server-side socket in Socket.io returns wrong namespace when 'connect'

Tags: node.js, namespaces, socket.io

I'm using Socket.io - 1.0.6 with express.

and trying below code.

Server

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connect', function(socket){
     console.log("server nsp->%s", socket.nsp.name);  
     //<-- printed always "server nsp->/", In my thought, it should print "/custom_nsp".
});
```

Client

```
var socket = io.connect("http://mysocket.io/custom_nsp");
socket.on('connect', function(){
     console.log("client nsp->%s", socket.nsp);   
     //<-- printed correctly "client nsp->/custom_nsp"
});
```

I don't know why server socket's namespce is always "/".

Do i anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because custom namespaces handling must be performed with `.of` method (see [docs](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#custom-namespaces)).

If you modify your server-side code as follows:

```
io.of('/custom_nsp').on('connect', function(socket) {
    console.log("server nsp->%s", socket.nsp.name);  //server nsp->/custom_nsp
});
```

you will get what you expect.

But it's still unclear why the default namespace handler fires even when connecting to `/custom_nsp`.

Comment: My trying is for dynamic assign custom namespace from client side. so server side .of() is useless for me. orz.

Comment: @nurinamu AFAIK, you can't do it with namespaces. But, maybe [rooms](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#rooms) would help. Client may emit an event (let's say, `socket.emit('join_room', {roomName: 'custom_room'})`), and server joins that socket to needed room.

Comment: Thx, I changed my routine as you suggested.